# Do I need synchronization to read and write a common cache file in a multithread environment?

Tags: multithreading

Consider the following algorithm, which is running on multiple threads at the same time:

```
for (i=0; i<10000; i++) {
  z = rand(0,50000);
  if (isset(cache[z])) results[z] = cache[z];
  else {
     result = z*100;
     cache[z] = result;
     results[z] = result;
  }
```

}

The `cache` and `results` are both shared variables among the threads. If this algorithm runs as it is, without synchronization, what kind of errors can occur? If two threads try to write concurrently to `cache[z]` or `results[z]` can data be lost, or plain and simply the data will be accepted by the thread that won the 'race-condition'?

A more concrete example of a question: let's say Thread A and Thread B both try to write to `cache[10]` at the same time the number 1000, and in the same time, Thread C tries to read the data that is in `cache[10]`. Can the read operation of Thread C finish, in an intermitent sate, let's say, as `100`, and then Thread C will continue working with the incorrect data?

**USE CASE**: A real life use case for which I am asking this question, is hashtabled caches. If all of the Threads will use the same hashtable cache, and they will read and write data from and to it, if the data they write to a specific key will always be the same, do I need to synchronize these read and write operations?

Comment: What language is this code in? What threading standard are you coding to?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am using `PHP` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody could possibly know. Different languages, compiler, CPUs, platforms, and threading standards could handle this in entirely different ways. There's no way anyone can know what some future compiler, CPU, or platform might do. Unless the documentation or specification for the language or threading standard says what will happen in this case, there is absolutely no way to know what might happen. Of course, if something you're using guarantees particular behavior in this case, then what is guaranteed to happen will happen (unless it's broken).

At one time, there didn't exist any CPUs that buffered writes such that they could be visible out-of-order. But if you wrote code under the assumption that this meant that writes would never become visible out-of-order, that code would be broken on pretty much every modern platform.

This sad tale repeated over and over with numerous compiler optimizations that people never expected compilers to make but that compilers later made. Some of the aliasing fiascos come to mind.

Making decisions that require you to imagine correctly possible future evolutions of computing seems extremely unwise and has failed repeatedly, sometimes catastrophically, in the past.